# Irish Grid Reference to Latitude and Longitude

Tags: r, spatial, latitude-longitude, r-sf

I'm looking into buildings that are of a listed status (really old buildings), and have a dataframe which contains a of locations that use the Irish Grid Reference system.

An example of one of these would be: C5288 2028

I need a way of converting this list into Latitude and Longitude, but for the life of me I cannot find a simple way of having a package convert the Irish Grid to Latitude and Longitude.

From googling around it looks like Irish Grid Reference numbers are based on CRS 29903, but I could be wrong.

Assuming that the Dataframe is called 'NI' and the Grid Reference variable is called 'TxtIGRef' could anyone think of any spatial package, such as SF, that can convert from said references to Lat/Lon?

I'd be extremely grateful of any assistance that you can provide.

Comment: Possible additional reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827313/plotting-utm-coordinates/66828038#66828038

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully I managed to find some kind soul who had already dealt with this in the past and so was able to help me with some of the code.

This has to be dealt with in two stages. First the grid reference has to be converted to eastings and northings and then you can convert that to lat/long.

You'll need the geosphere and proj4 packages.

```
    library(geosphere)
library(proj4)

# Example data
Northern_Ireland <- data.frame(
  TxtIgRef = c("C5288 2028", "C5488 2018"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Add blank Latitude and Longitude columns

Northern_Ireland$Latitude <- NA
Northern_Ireland$Longitude <- NA

# Define the projection for Irish Grid Reference

proj <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=53.5 +lon_0=-8 +k=1.000035 +x_0=200000 +y_0=250000 +ellps=airy +datum=ire65 +units=m +no_defs"

# Function to convert Irish Grid Reference to lat/lon

igr_to_lat_lon <- function(igr) {
  
# Split the Irish Grid Reference into easting and northing parts
  
parts <- strsplit(igr, " ")[[1]]
easting <- as.numeric(substr(parts[1], 2, nchar(parts[1])))
northing <- as.numeric(parts[2])

# Convert Irish Grid Reference to lat/lon

lat_lon <- project(cbind(easting, northing), proj, inverse = TRUE)

return(lat_lon)
}

# Loop through the data frame and populate Latitude and Longitude columns
for (i in 1:nrow(Northern_Ireland)) {
igr <- Northern_Ireland$TxtIgRef[i]
lat_lon <- igr_to_lat_lon(igr)
Northern_Ireland$Latitude[i] <- lat_lon[2]
Northern_Ireland$Longitude[i] <- lat_lon[1] }
```